# FineUploader works with one file, doesn't work with multiple

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fine-uploader

I'm using FineUploader in a Wordpress plugin:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-load.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/media.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-admin/includes/image.php');

if(!$_FILES) exit();

if(isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {$files = $_FILES['qqfile'];}

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$file_name = $files['name'];
$file_name = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . basename($file_name);
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$file_post = wp_handle_upload($files,$upload_overrides); //Posts File

$file_link = $file_post['file'];
$file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($file_link), null); //File Extension

$post_name = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file_link)); //Post Name

$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $file_link,
    'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
    'post_title' => $post_name,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_name, $_POST['post_id']);

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file_name);

$attach_final = wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
$response['data'] = $_FILES;
$response['success'] = 'true';

echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```

This code works fine, when I'm uploading one file only. When I drag&drop multiple files, the upload fails (the file is not uploaded at all).

My FineUploader code is:

```
$("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: Ajax.ajaxurl,
        params: {
            action: 'attach_files',
            post_id: $('#post_id').val()
        }
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        endpoint: '/uploads'
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Based on comment, the response is:

```
[FineUploader 4.2.2] responseText = {"data":{"qqfile":{"name":"6-7-8.JPG","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/home\/www\/domain.com\/tmp\/phpGI9bVU","error":0,"size":135947}},"success":"true"} jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:16
[FineUploader 4.2.2] Received response status 200 with body: {"data":{"qqfile":{"name":"6-7-8.JPG","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/home\/www\/domain.com\/tmp\/phpGI9bVU","error":0,"size":135947}},"success":"true"} jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:16
XHR finished loading: POST "http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php". jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:18
[FineUploader 4.2.2] xhr - server response received for 1 jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:16
[FineUploader 4.2.2] responseText = {"data":{"qqfile":{"name":"26feb-jazz (1).jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/home\/www\/domain.com\/tmp\/phpROrYrz","error":0,"size":75475}},"success":"true"} jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:16
[FineUploader 4.2.2] Received response status 200 with body: {"data":{"qqfile":{"name":"26feb-jazz (1).jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/home\/www\/domain.com\/tmp\/phpROrYrz","error":0,"size":75475}},"success":"true"} jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:16
XHR finished loading: POST "http://nevestam.cz/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php". jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:18
[FineUploader 4.2.2] xhr - server response received for 2 jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:16
[FineUploader 4.2.2] responseText = {"data":{"qqfile":{"name":"Anna Garcia.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/home\/www\/domain.com\/tmp\/phpIDGCUh","error":0,"size":254890}},"success":"true"} jquery.fineuploader.min.js?ver=3.9:16
[FineUploader 4.2.2] Received response status 200 with body: {"data":{"qqfile":{"name":"Anna Garcia.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/home\/www\/domain.com\/tmp\/phpIDGCUh","error":0,"size":254890}},"success":"true"}
```

Comment: You never bother checking the `['error']` parameter in $_FILES. e.g. have you tried doing `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what's really coming across?

Comment: Please see edits. I did check the $_FILES array, it looks the same no matter if I'm sending one file or multiple files.

Comment: The files are uploaded without issue.  It looks like there are some issues with your server code however.  Have a look at the request transcripts.  One requests is sent for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - it seems the problem was in the

```
$file_name = $files['name'];
```

I changed it to

```
$file_name = sanitize_file_name($files['name']);
```

and it is working now. I have no idea how that was related to the single vs multiple upload though.